# Python List Comprehension in Website Blocker

Tags: python, list-comprehension, any

In line 2, the any() method gets 'website' from the list comprehension then takes step based on boolean value. It works just fine. But, I can't write this line in basic syntax (using only if, for, any, in) without the list comprehension syntax. I know it's best to use list comprehension but this is for education.

```
for line in content:
    if not any(website in line for website in websites):
        file.write(line)
```

I tried something like this and I knew this won't give correct result.

```
for line in lines:
    for website in websites:
        if any(website):
            print(line)
```

Full code can be found here: https://github.com/shaanlearn/pypractice/blob/main/websiteBlocker

Line Number: 39-41

Comment: So what is the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can expand the **list comprehension** as following

```
for line in content:
    result = []
    for website in websites:
        result.append(website in line)
    if not any(result):
        file.write(line)
```

Comment: Hi @pranta-palit, thanks for quick response, this one worked! 
I have a question though, when I printed result list, it gives bool value. like this: 
`
[False]
[False, False]
[True]
[True, False]
[True]
[True, True]

`

Comment: `result` is a list that contains our query in boolean, as we queried for if any of the listed websites are in line or not. That's why result contains those boolean values. Then if you apply `any()` method, it will return true if any item of the boolean list is true, again, if any item is true in boolean list that means one or many websites exists in that line, it will not write the line in file, if the line contains no listed websites, the line will be written in file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
for line in lines:
    for website in websites:
        if website in line:
            break
    print(line)
```

Comment: print line should be indented a step back

Answer (score 1):

another way to expand:

```
for line in content:
    for website in websites:
        if website in line:
            break
    file.write(line)
```

Comment: as the first loop is iterating over `content`, we are getting a new line each time and checking if any websites (in websites) in line exists or not, if not then writing the line in file.